# How to construct an MongoDB Linq Any() query by comparing a sub-field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to construct the following nested query such that it will run on my entities in C# but be properly translated through the C# Driver to a MongoDB Query;

```
lpn = new List<PN> { new PN("/standard"), new PN("/my") };n
Collection.AsQueryable<T>
    (o => o.pns.Any(pf => lpn.Any(pn => pn.n == pf.n))
```

So that's valid C#. I'm trying to match an array of values against an array of values, but I get this error in the driver stack;

```
Result Message: 
Test method MyLib.Tests.Models.ProjectTest.DBImportExcelProject threw exception: 
System.NotSupportedException: Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyLib.DomainModels.lpn].
Result StackTrace:  
at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Utils.BsonSerializationInfoFinder.GetSerializationInfo(Expression node, Dictionary`2 serializationInfoCache) in d:\vs11Projects\ThirdParty\mongo-csharp-driver\Driver\Linq\Utils\BsonSerializationInfoFinder.cs:line 64
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Utils.BsonSerializationInfoHelper.GetSerializationInfo(Expression node) in d:\vs11Projects\ThirdParty\mongo-csharp-driver\Driver\Linq\Utils\BsonSerializationInfoHelper.cs:line 48
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.PredicateTranslator.BuildAnyQuery(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression) in d:\vs11Projects\ThirdParty\mongo-csharp-driver\Driver\Linq\Translators\PredicateTranslator.cs:line 133
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.PredicateTranslator.BuildMethodCallQuery(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression) in d:\vs11Projects\ThirdParty\mongo-csharp-driver\Driver\Linq\Translators\PredicateTranslator.cs:line 735
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.PredicateTranslator.BuildQuery(Expression expression) in d:\vs11Projects\ThirdParty\mongo-csharp-driver\Driver\Linq\Translators\PredicateTranslator.cs:line 73
...
```

Which I can appreciate since it's trying to put an `$in:[]` query into another query.

This is what an object in the collection looks like;

```
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("50a5633292c3d22270ac2256"),
            "pns" : [
                    {
                            "n" : "/standard",
                            "ns" : {
                                    "v" : "standard"
                            }
                    }
            ]
    }
```

So `pns` is an array of `PN` types, so I can't simply use `Contains()` because I don't want to match the whole `PN` structure, just the `n` field. I've tried various other constructions.

This is the closest thing I've been able to come up with in the shell;

```
db.collection.find({
    "pns": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "n": "/standard",
        }
    }
}).count();
```

But I can't even find a way to convert that to a Linq expression.

**Question**
Is it possible to build a linq query that matches any array member of `lpn` within `pns` but only matching against the `n` field? Or am I going to have to build these queries by hand?

**Update**

I think I almost have it. I figure I need to convert to a string array before I can do anything sensible with the query, and I don't think I can do that in Linq. So this works;

```
var strArray = new[] { "/standard", "/my" };
Collection.AsQueryable<T>(o => o.pns.Any(pn => pn.n.In(strArray)));
```

which gives me;

```
{
    "pns": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "n": {
                "$in": [
                  "/standard",
                  "/my"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But unfortunately, the Driver isn't smart enough to accept this;

```
Collection.AsQueryable<T>(o => o.pns.Any(pn => pn.n.In(lpn.Select(pfn => pfn.n))));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the Contains linq method...

```
var strArray = new[] { "/standard", "/my" };
Collection.AsQueryable<T>(o => o.pns.Any(pn => strArray.Contains(pn.n)));
```

Note, you can do this with a `List<string>` as well in your case.  Anything that implements `IEnumerable<T>`...

Comment: This is untested...  Let me know if it doesn't and I'll work on it when I get home.

Comment: That's cool thanks. It produces exactly the same json Query as my In() version. Which makes me wonder - why do you suggest Contains() vs In()? I think the key to it here was realising that I needed to split out the query values into a string array. I had been trying to build the query using an array of objects (List<PN>). If there's a way to do that inline without building a string array first it has completely evaded me.

Comment: You can do it with the objects as well.  However, using the objects would then compare the whole object as opposed to just the string value.  I suggest contains because it is a built-in Linq method as opposed to In which is a LingToMongo method.  Hence, one couples you to MongoDB and one doesn't.

Comment: Fantastic, I'll use your Contains variant for that very reason. Yeah, the object query is the easy one. I started there, but there's a whole list of reasons why that's not the comparison I want to use. An optional DisplayName property is just one.

Comment: My original Any(Any()) query - could that even be translated to the shell?

Comment: Your translation into the $in array is the correct translation of your original Any(Any) query into the shell.  We could probably recognize something like this in the linq provider, but it would be difficult.